# Java: Using a hashmap, retrieving all values and calling methods

Tags: java, android, object, methods, hashmap

I have a need to store a list of dynamically created objects in a way where they can all be retrieved and their methods called on demand.

As far as I can see for the list and creation, a HashMap fits my needs but i'm a bit puzzled on recalling the objects and calling their methods using the HashMap.

Just as a reference, let me give you a little code:

Here is the HashMap:

```
Map<String, Object> unitMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

// here is how I put an object in the Map notice i'm passing coordinates to the constructor:
unitMap.put("1", new Worker(240, 240));
unitMap.put("2", new Worker(240, 240));
```

Now I need to create a method that retrieves every object in the hashmap and call a method from each object. is this possible or can the created objects only be referenced directly. If so, is there another way to call a method of all existing instances of a class dynamically (in other words, on user input)?

Comment: HashMaps have unique keys, so you can only insert one object for each key value ("1" in your case). To access all members, just iterate over the container as in the answer below.

Comment: @Kerrek Sorry typo, I meant to make each entry a different key.

Comment: Don't forget to "accept" an answer that you find useful, so we'll welcome you back for your next question! :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure. You can do this:

```
for (Object thing : unitMap.values()) {
    // use "thing" here
}
```

If you need the keys too, you can either get just the keys:

```
for (String key : unitMap.keySet()) {
    // use "key" here
}
```

or both the keys and values together:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : unitMap.entrySet()) {
    // use "entry.getKey()" and "entry.getValue()"
}
```

In all the above cases, each entry in the map is traversed one by one. So at the end of the loop, you'll have processed all the entries in the map.

Comment: I am a tad confused though. in the above code lets say I want to retrieve the coordinates of the objects (Which ARE different kinds of objects) using a method each object has called getCord(). How do I do this using the above method? would I use "thing" as sort of a variable and put 'thing.getCord()' in the body of the loop? Sorry i'm very beginner so I need specificity. lol

Comment: In the third instance, `entry.getValue()` is an object of type `Worker`; in the first instance, `thing` is likewise an object of type Worker. If there is a `Worker::getCoord()` member function, then indeed you can say `think.getCoord()` or `entry.getValue().getCoord()`.

Comment: @Kerrek SB in my code when I use the first example, thing is only being recognized as an object, and not as type worker, thus when I use thing.getCoord(); it's not being recognized as a member function. I guess worst case, I can just create a hashmap for each object type, but do you have and idea why its not working for each object type?

Comment: @cody: Ideally, you _would_ use a different map for each object type, if those types are not related at all. But assuming you just want to stash them as `Object`s in the map, you should cast the object to the right type first. e.g., `if (thing instanceof Worker) { return ((Worker) thing).getCoord(); }`

Comment: Ah perfect. Ok thanks for all your help, I think i'll rewrite to implement separate HashMaps, shouldn't be that much trouble, and it will actually have a couple of advantages for my goal.

Answer (score 1):

If all of the values in the Map are `Worker` objects, you should declare your map to be of type `Map<String, Worker>`.  This way, when you pull a value out of the map, it will be typed as a `Worker`.  This way you can call any method declared on `Worker` as opposed to having to check the type at runtime using `instanceof`.

If the map holds different values, and you need to keep the value type as `Object`, it may be advantageous to use an interface to define the method that you want to call for each different object type.

If you do not know what method you want to run on the values until runtime, and the map can hold different values, you will just have to do what you are currently doing, and use `Map<String, Object>`.

Finally, to get the values of the map, you do just as Chris Jester-Young mentioned before me.  The biggest advantage, as I said previously, is that your objects will be typed, and you will have no need for casting/instanceof checking.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to put all values from hashMap on a List, hope it helps.

```
private List<String> getValuesFromHashMap(HashMap<String, String> hashMap) {

    List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String item : hashMap.values()) {
        values.add(item);
    }

    return values;
}
```